# Can you easily deploy a django website to IONOS (1&1)

Tags: django, hosting

I'm currently working on a website using the django framework and I found a good price for a domain on IONOS. I was wondering whether you can deploy a django website to IONOS in a simple way. I haven't been able to find good solutions online and I don't really want to switch to a different web hosting provider. In case I have to, could you recommend any good services (I need the website to use https and to be relatively scaleable).

I've tried looking for alternatives that are 'Django friendly' but they don't really meet my needs.